# where on the filesystem do user-generated system scripts go?

Tags: filesystems, directory-structure

I have a couple command line php scripts and also php pages that call the same class file. Instead of having mutiple copies of it floating around, I want to put `class.myApi.php` in one central location on the filesystem. All files will then reference that one single file. Where does it belong?  Does it belong in `/usr/bin` ?

Comment: Is this a per-user problem or a global one?

Comment: @XQYZ I don't understand the question. Root uses it in cron (I think) and then whatever Apache user uses it in serving pages.

Comment: Well if it had been a user problem then the location would be in your home. So I was just checking here. It's a difficult question, but since apache uses it anywhere but your www directory seems wrong imho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest either `/usr/local/share/php/your-app-name` or `/opt/local/share/php/your-app-name`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most appropriate place would be

```
/usr/lib/yourLibraryName
```

See the [Filesystem Hierarchie Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLIBLIBRARIESFORPROGRAMMINGANDPA) for more information.

Comment: That would be appropriate for packaged files belonging or built for the target distribution. Locally contributed files shouldn't go under /usr (outside /usr/local).